# Give image Address from mysql database show in html

Tags: html, css, laravel

I have a list of Artists that have image addresses in database. Now I want to show the image in my HTML-template but I don't know how I can do it.

Template:

```
@foreach($artists as $artist)
   <h2 class="services_h2 center">Artists</h2>
      <div class="ppp col-sm-4">
        <div class="hovereffect">
          <img  style="padding:10px;" class="img-responsive" src="
             {{asset('image\{{$artist->Artist_Image}}')}}" alt="">
             </div>
             <h3 style="padding-top:5px;">{{$artist->Artist_Name}}</h3>
              <p>{{$artist->Artist_Alias}}</p>
       </div>
 @endforeach
```

When I use this code `Artist_Image` it renders the string as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Changes Images name in database to images\jdj.jpg and used this code in Html file.
`src="{{ asset( $artist->Artist_Image)}}"`

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
{{ asset('image\' . $artist->Artist_Image) }}
```

Comment: I Give this Error `"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'layouts' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'"`